# Sqlite how to escape values to prevent SQL injection

Tags: node.js, sqlite, security, sql-injection

Could anybody tell me how do I escape input values to prevent SQL injection? I have a user authentication app and I need to somehow import some security.

My validation looks like this:

```
//Validation 
req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password must have at least 6 characters').len(6,20);
req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);
```

And then I `INSERT` some values as follows:

```
var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO users ( id, name, email, password, salt) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
               stmt.run([ name, hashEmail(email,'salt'), hashPassword(password,'salt'), 'salt'], function(error){  //.....
```

I have been told this is not really secure way to import values, but as long as I am not really experienced in internet security I would require some help from you.

Regards

Comment: your code is not vulnerable to sql injections. you are doing fine: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/57

Comment: Thanks, gonna have a look into it.

Comment: Values in parameters (`?`) do *not* need to be escaped.

Comment: So this is just all good? No security needed?

Comment: In addition to my answer, please note that using a simple hash to store passwords is not enough anymore. The best practice is to use PBKDF2 or Bcrypt, and you should not generate salts yourself, let your chosen algorithm do that correctly for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you are already using a parameterized query correctly (instead of constructing a string of SQL mixed with request parameters, you used `?` in your query to designate places where parameters will be substituted when the SQL statement is executed), **your code shown above is already fine and not vulnerable to SQL injection**.

It would only be vulnerable to SQLi if you concatenated those variables with the SQL string itself.

Comment: Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

In case if you can't use parameters in your scenarios, then you can try using [sqlstring package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlstring) that has several functions for escaping different things:

- `escape` - escapes query values (e.g. stirngs, lists, dates and other JS objects)
- `escapeId` - for escaping SQL identifiers (database / table / column name)

```js
import * as SqlString from "sqlstring";

SqlString.escape("bad value");
// replaceAll because it wraps identifier in `
SqlString.escapeId("bad identifier").replaceAll("`", "");
```

The downside of the package is that it's designed to work only with MySQL (issues related to problems with escaping characters for other DBs are closed with such notice), so you'll need an extra step to escape quotes and double quotes.